# what different techniques can be used to merge the three lists into the one. What would be the most elegant approach?

Tags: java-stream

I am trying to merge 3 List of object based on common object id as below.
I want to use some advance technic rather than this below code to loop 3 times.

```
    employeeSalaries.forEach(System.out::println);
    employeeList.forEach(System.out::println);
    employeeDetails.forEach(System.out::println);

    for (Employee e : employeeList)
    {
        EmployeeAll ea = new EmployeeAll();
        for (EmployeeSalary es : employeeSalaries)
        {
            for(EmployeeDetails ed : employeeDetails) {
                if (e.getEmployeeId() == es.getEmployeeId() && 
                    e.getEmployeeId()==ed.getEmployeeId()) {
                    ea.setEmployeeId(e.getEmployeeId());
                    ea.setEmployeeMessage(ed.getEmployeeMessage());
                    ea.setEmployeeName(e.getEmployeeName());
                    ea.setSalary(es.getSalary());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        eaList.add(ea);
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------------List ------------------------");
    eaList.forEach(System.out::println);``
```

Comment: Hi Hltesh, An interesting problem.  You need to ask a question, like what different techniques can be used to merge the three lists into the one.  What would be the most elegant approach?  As it stands, readers will only wish you luck with your task.

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:use google guava's `Streams` to merge two stream.**

*First,you need to sort three list by `employeeId`*

```java
List<EmployeeSalary> employeeSalaries = getEmployeeSalaries();
employeeSalaries.sort(Comparator.comparing(EmployeeSalary::getEmployeeId));

List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getEmployeeId));

List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails = getEmployeeDetails();
employeeDetails.sort(Comparator.comparing(EmployeeDetails::getEmployeeId));
```

*Second,use guava's Streams.zip method to merege:*

```java
Stream<EmployeeAll> tmpStream = Streams.zip(employeeDetails.stream(), employees.stream(), (employeeDetails1, employee) -> {
    EmployeeAll employeeAll = new EmployeeAll();
    employeeAll.setEmployeeId(employeeDetails1.getEmployeeId());
    employeeAll.setEmployeeMessage(employeeDetails1.getEmployeeMessage());
    employeeAll.setEmployeeName(employee.getEmployeeName());
    return employeeAll;
});

Stream<EmployeeAll> result = Streams.zip(tmpStream, employeeSalaries.stream(), (employeeAll, employeeSalary) -> {
    employeeAll.setSalary(employeeSalary.getSalary());
    return employeeAll;
});
```

**Method2: for list length different and not contains all ids**

*First,change the list to map which id is map's key.Time complexity is 3*O(n)*

```
List<EmployeeDetails> details = getEmployeeDetails();
List<Employee> employees = getEmployees();
List<EmployeeSalary> salaries = getEmployeeSalaries();

Map<String, List<Employee>> employeeMap = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeId));
Map<String, List<EmployeeSalary>> salariesMap = salaries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeSalary::getEmployeeId));
Map<String, List<EmployeeDetails>> detailsMap = details.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeDetails::getEmployeeId));
```

*Second,for-each loop all ids and assembly object.Time complexity is 3*O(n) and max n equals to sum of three list size*

```
Stream.concat(Stream.concat(detailsMap.keySet().stream(), employeeMap.keySet().stream()), salariesMap.keySet().stream())
        .distinct()
        .map(s -> {
            EmployeeAll employeeAll = new EmployeeAll();
            if (detailsMap.containsKey(s)) {
                employeeAll.setEmployeeMessage(detailsMap.get(s).get(0).getEmployeeMessage());
            }
            if (employeeMap.containsKey(s)) {
                employeeAll.setEmployeeName(employeeMap.get(s).get(0).getEmployeeName());
            }
            if (salariesMap.containsKey(s)) {
                employeeAll.setSalary(salariesMap.get(s).get(0).getSalary());
            }
            employeeAll.setEmployeeId(s);
            return employeeAll;
        }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Does it make sense to sort the whole list of objects if the object size is around 1000 to 5000. Also for stream zip we will need to extra dependencies right??

Comment: Also, will this help if there is issue in data, say 1 empolyeeId is missing in one List

Comment: if list contains more element,sort is wasteful,but zip need order,

Comment: If you or anyone can suggest any other technique of implementing it please

Comment: This approach assumes that all lists have the same ids.  What happens if the employee details or salary tables do not have an entry for the employee?  Other than the sort, there is no matching by ID.

Comment: if list length is different and not contains all ids,for-each is the way to merge.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.  If your lists are long, you could make the search methods more efficient - this is just a straight unordered search.

```
public class CombineEmployeeLists {
    
    public List<EmployeeAll> combineLists(
            List<EmployeeSalary>    employeeSalaries,
            List<Employee>          employeeList,
            List<EmployeeDetails>   employeeDetailList) {
        
        return employeeList.stream()
            .map(employee -> {
                EmployeeAll ea = new EmployeeAll();
                ea.setId(employee.getId());
                ea.setEmployeeName(employee.getEmployeeName());
                ea.setEmployeeMessage(getEmployeeMessage(employeeDetailList, employee));
                ea.setEmployeeSalary(getEmployeeSalary(employeeSalaries, employee));
                return ea;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    }

    private String getEmployeeMessage(List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetailList, Employee employee) {
        
        return employeeDetailList.stream()
                .filter(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getId() == employee.getId())
                .map(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getEmployeeMessage())
                .findFirst().orElse("");
        
    }

    private BigDecimal getEmployeeSalary(List<EmployeeSalary> employeeSalaries, Employee employee) {

        return employeeSalaries.stream()
                .filter(employeeSalary -> employeeSalary.getId() == employee.getId())
                .map(employeeSalary -> employeeSalary.getSalary())
                .findFirst().orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have more questions on this.. Here in this example I have just shown 1 attribute in each object but if I have multiple attributes say 10-15 in all 3 list. Like we have salary is one attribute where you have created 1 method getEmployeeSalary, should I create such method 10 time to stream through. Will that be good in performace?

Comment: Rather than calling a method for each attribute, you could return the data structure such as `getEmployeeDetail()` and then call the getters for each attribute from the emplyeeDetail class.  So in the first stream, you'd have `ea.setEmployeeMessage(getEmployeeDetail(...).getEmployeeMessage());`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating lookup Maps based on the common object id. I've left the error handling & null checking up to you, but here is a working example.

```java
import lombok.Value;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class Main {
    @Value static class Employee {
        int id;
        String name;
    }

    @Value static class Salary {
        int id;
        int salary;
    }

    @Value static class Detail {
        int id;
        String msg;
    }

    @Value static class PersonnelFile {
        int id;
        String name;
        int salary;
        String msg;

        PersonnelFile(Employee employee, Salary salary, Detail detail) {
            this.id = employee.id;
            this.name = employee.name;
            this.salary = salary.salary;
            this.msg = detail.msg;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee(1,"John"), new Employee(2,"Smith"));
        List<Salary> salaries = List.of(new Salary(1, 99), new Salary(2, 100));
        List<Detail> details = List.of(new Detail(1, "foo"), new Detail(2, "bar"));
        System.out.println(merge(employees, salaries, details));
    }

    static List<PersonnelFile> merge(List<Employee> employees, List<Salary> salaries, List<Detail> details) {
        Map<Integer, Salary> salaryById = salaries.stream().collect(toMap(Salary::getId, identity()));
        Map<Integer, Detail> detailById = details.stream().collect(toMap(Detail::getId, identity()));
        return employees.stream()
                .map(employee -> new PersonnelFile(employee, salaryById.get(employee.id), detailById.get(employee.id)))
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```